# Strange behavior of 'SquareFreeQ'

Tags: functions, prime-numbers, number-theory

What is the cause of this strange behavior of `SquareFreeQ` while `PrimePowerQ` works correctly:

```
Range[20] /. x_ /; SquareFreeQ[x] -> 0

0[0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 18, 0, 20]

Range[20] /. x_ /; PrimePowerQ[x] -> 0

{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 12, 0, 14, 15, 0, 0, 18, 0, 20}
```

I use Mathematica 13.

Comment: Use `x_Integer` instead of `x_`.

Comment: Or use `Replace[Range[20],x_ /; SquareFreeQ[x] -> 0,1]`. As others have noted, `ReplaceAll` looks at (and may be used to replace) the Head of the expression. Compare **Range[2] /. x_ /; SquareFreeQ[x] -> f[x]**, giving **f[List][f[1], f[2]]** with **Replace[Range[2],x_ /; SquareFreeQ[x] -> f[x],1]**, giving **{f[1], f[2]}**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to evaluate this: `SquareFreeQ[List]`

It turns out that List is, indeed, square-free. So, it was replaced (it was the head of the expression, so that's where the 0 was placed).

On the other hand, `PrimePowerQ[List]` is False, so the head List was not replaced.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Thread[SquareFreeQ[Range[20]]
(*{True, True, True, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, False, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, False}*)

PrimePowerQ[Range[20]]
(*{False, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, False, False, True, True, False, True, False}*)
```

And you can apply Alan's suggestion:

```
Range[20] /. x_Integer /; SquareFreeQ[x] -> 0
(*{0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 18, 0, 20}*)

Range[20] /. x_Integer /; PrimePowerQ[x] -> 0
(*{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 12, 0, 14, 15, 0, 0, 18, 0, 20}*)
```